# how to disable tab in tabs in native base

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-base

This is my code for my simple project in native-base (React-native)

```
<container>
    <Tabs initialPage={0}>
        <Tab heading={
            <TabHeading>
                <Text/>
            </TabHeading>
        }>
            <FirstScreen>
        </Tab>
        <Tab heading={
            <TabHeading>
                <Text/>
            </TabHeading>
        }>
            <SecondScreen>
        </Tab>
    </Tabs>

</container>
```

How can I disable the tab for the second screen?
disable means, still viewable but unclickable.
Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by disable tab?

Comment: @Vivek_Neel, I edited my question thanks!

Comment: Use `locked` prop with second tab and see if that's what you wanted?

Comment: @Vivek_Neel, I added locked in my second tab. It became <Tab locked = {true}> I also tried <Tab locked> but didnt work :(

Comment: locked only disable the horizontal gesture

Answer (score 0):

how about using two tabs? one for the active state and one for the disabled state? you can use a condition to differentiate.

```
<container>
<Tabs initialPage={0}>
    <Tab heading={
        <TabHeading>
            <Text/>
        </TabHeading>
    }>
        <FirstScreen>
    </Tab>

    { your condition for active tab && (<Tab heading={
        <TabHeading>
            <ActiveText/>
        </TabHeading>
    }>
        <ActiveScreen>
    </Tab>)}

    { your condition for disabled tab && (<Tab heading={
        <TabHeading>
            <DisabledText/> //maybe you could have grey color
        </TabHeading>
    }>
        <DisabledScreen> //you could show why the tab is disabled
    </Tab>)}

</Tabs>
</container>
```

the disabled tab will be clickable. but you can control the content. this is not exactly what you wanted. but giving you this since i found no other way. :)

Comment: our last resort is to hide the tab instead of disabling it. same with our last hope :)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Tabs itself is not possible.
Instead u can style the views based on some state with opaque grey background color without any onPress events in them.

```
if(this.state.disable)
{
 <Tabs style={diabled}>
 </Tabs>
}
else
{
 <Tabs style={enabled}>
 </Tabs>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make the Tabs component non clickable by wrapping it in a view and set pointerEvents to "none"

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
    <Tabs>
       ....
    </Tabs>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite renderTab props in scrollable tab

```
<Tabs 
  tabBarUnderlineStyle={{height:0}}
  renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab renderTab={this.renderTab}}
  locked={true}
>
```

and change renderTab in your code to accept disable prop from  component like this

```
    renderTab(
    name,
    page,
    isTabActive,
    onPressHandler,
    onLayoutHandler,
    tabStyle,
    activeTabStyle,
    textStyle,
    activeTextStyle,
    tabHeaderStyle,
    tabFontSize
  ) {
    const headerContent =
      typeof name !== "string" ? name.props.children : undefined;
    const { activeTextColor, inactiveTextColor } = this.props;
    const textColor = isTabActive ? activeTextColor : inactiveTextColor;
    const fontWeight = isTabActive ? "bold" : "normal";
    // const fontSize = tabFontSize;

    if (typeof name === "string") {
      return (
        <Button
          key={`${name}_${page}`}
          onPress={() => onPressHandler(page)}
          onLayout={onLayoutHandler}
        >
          <TabHeading
            scrollable
            style={isTabActive ? activeTabStyle : tabStyle}
            active={isTabActive}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                isTabActive ? activeTextStyle : textStyle,
                { fontSize: tabFontSize }
              ]}
            >
              {name}
            </Text>
          </TabHeading>
        </Button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Button
          key={v4()}
          onPress={() => onPressHandler(page)}
          onLayout={onLayoutHandler}
          disabled={name.props.disabled}
        >
          <TabHeading scrollable style={tabHeaderStyle} active={isTabActive}>
            {headerContent}
          </TabHeading>
        </Button>
      );
    }
}
```

You can find original code from this path:
node_module -> native-base -> src -> basic -> tabs -> scrollableTabBar.js